# How to access class constants in Twig?

Tags: php, templates, twig

I have a few class constants in my entity class, e.g.:

```
class Entity {
    const TYPE_PERSON = 0;
    const TYPE_COMPANY = 1;
}
```

In normal PHP I often do `if($var == Entity::TYPE_PERSON)` and I would like to do this kind of stuff in Twig. Is it possible?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

```
{% if var == constant('Namespace\\Entity::TYPE_PERSON') %}
{# or #}
{% if var is constant('Namespace\\Entity::TYPE_PERSON') %}
```

See documentation for the [`constant` function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html) and the [`constant` test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/constant.html).

Comment: You should add testing contants with object instance to your anwser `{% if var is constant('TYPE_PERSON', object) %}`

Comment: Worked when i typed the namespace, like @message's message.

Answer (score 253):

Just to save your time. If you need to access class constants under namespace, use

```
{{ constant('Acme\\DemoBundle\\Entity\\Demo::MY_CONSTANT') }}
```

Comment: Its important to note that the double slashes are important. I wasted a few minutes because I didn't put the double backslashes in.

Comment: Wow, that's ugly :-) It would be nice if Twig could make constants look like other properties / variables. eg `{% if var == object.MY_CONSTANT %}`

Comment: also works with `url()` twig function :)

Answer (score 35):

As of 1.12.1 you can read constants from object instances as well:

```
{% if var == constant('TYPE_PERSON', entity)
```

Comment: This only works if entity is an instance of Entity, I think that the question is about accessing a constant without a defined object in the template.

Comment: In that case you just write `{{ constant('Namespace\\Classname::CONSTANT_NAME') }}` ([doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html))

Comment: What's good about this is that it makes it easy to use a Twig variable instead of a string literal as the constant name.

Comment: Just for clarity. If you want to pass constants within a class as twig vriable and use it like `{{ constant('TYPE_PERSON', entity) }}`, it's possible to do following (instantiate Entity class) `$this->render('index.html.twig', ['entity' => new Entity()]);`

Comment: I wonder if you can use `constant('SOME_CONSTANT', form.getFoo())` where `getFoo()` returns the custom FormType PHP class.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using namespaces

```
{{ constant('Namespace\\Entity::TYPE_COMPANY') }}
```

Important! Use double slashes, instead of single

Answer (score 12):

**Edit: I've found better solution, [read about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499293/3749178)**

---

- [Read more about how to create and register extension in Twig documentation.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)
- [Read about Twig extensions in Symfony2 documentation.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

---

Let's say you have class:

```
namespace MyNamespace;
class MyClass
{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 'my_constant';
    const MY_CONSTANT2 = 'const2';
}
```

Create and register Twig extension:

```
class MyClassExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    { 
        return 'my_class_extension'; 
    }

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        $class = new \ReflectionClass('MyNamespace\MyClass');
        $constants = $class->getConstants();

        return array(
            'MyClass' => $constants
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can use constants in Twig like:

```
{{ MyClass.MY_CONSTANT }}
```

Comment: So defining a entire twig extension for each class is less "ugly" than using {{ constant('Acme\\DemoBundle\\Entity\\Demo::MY_CONSTANT') }} ? And what do you do when your class names overlaps ? you loose all the benefit of namespaces here

Comment: I have a similar solution, I might extract this to a bundle though. The problem with this solution is that you have reflection overhead. In symfony you can write a compiler pass to resolve this when the container is compiled.

Comment: @0x1gene You are right, class names can overlap. I silently assumed that  MyClass is not just any class, but a class which is very important within project. And used often enough so using `constant()` with FQN would be bothersome.

Comment: @DamianPolac do you know PHPStorm will prompt variable selection in twig file?

Comment: When you say "Now", you should probably be more specific what version you're referring to.

Answer (score 11):

In book best practices of Symfony there is a section with this issue:

> Constants can be used for example in your Twig templates thanks to the constant() function:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Post.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Post
{
    const NUM_ITEMS = 10;

   // ...
}
```

And use this constant in template twig:

```
<p>
    Displaying the {{ constant('NUM_ITEMS', post) }} most recent results.
</p>
```

Here the link:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options

Answer (score 4):

After some years I realized that my previous answer is not really so good. I have created extension that solves problem better. It's published as open source.

https://github.com/dpolac/twig-const

It defines new Twig operator `#` which let you access the class constant through any object of that class.

Use it like that:

`{% if entity.type == entity#TYPE_PERSON %}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'd never thought of this! If you'd like to use entity class names without instantiating objects, for example `User#TYPE_PERSON`, the `NodeExpression` class could be changed to something like this, which worked for me: `->raw('(constant(\'App\\Entity\\' . $this->getNode('left')->getAttribute('name') . '::' . $this->getNode('right')->getAttribute('name') . '\'))')`. Of course, this limits your classes to the `App\Entity` namespace, but I think that covers the most common use case.