# How to use access constants in twig file Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I have a class following:

```
class allConstants {
   //PREDEFINED ALL FIXED GROUPS  USING IN ACCOUNT MODULE 
    const GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT            = 'Bank Accounts';
    const GROUP_CURRENT_ASSETS          = 'Current Assets';
    const GROUP_LOAN_LIBILITIES         = 'Loan (Liabilities)';
    const GROUP_BANK_OD_ACCOUNT         = 'Bank OD a/c';
    const GROUP_CASH_IN_HAND  
 }
```

So I want to access these constants into twig file. So when I am using like following in twig :
 constant('\Edu\AccountBundle\Constants\allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT');

its showing an refrence erro that "constant" not define.
Please guide how to make it work. I am using symfony 2.3.7
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access class constants in Twig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611086/how-to-access-class-constants-in-twig)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if gropu is constant('allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT') %}
    the status attribute is exactly the same as allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT
{% endif %}
```

test constants from object instances

```
{% if gropu is constant('GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT', allConstants) %}
    the status attribute is exactly the same as allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I want value of the constants in twig. Suppose i want to check condation like: if(gropu ==allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT ){ So how to access the values of "GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT". here

Comment: This is showing same error : ReferenceError: constant is not defined

Comment: I am still getting error that group is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by Muhammad is right:

```
{% if group is constant('GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT', allConstants) %}
    the status attribute is exactly the same as allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT
{% endif %}
```

But you can use like this only with Twig >=1.12.1; with lower version, you can just use it from static classes, like this:

```
constant('allConstants::GROUP_BANK_ACCOUNT')
```